# В URL (Битрикс) оставить только символьный код товара. Возможно ли?

Tags: битрикс, чпу

На данный момент имеем ссылки вида:

```
https://site.com/catalog/sredstva-primenyaemye-pri-zabolevaniyakh-pecheni-i-zhelchevyvodyashchikh-putey/essentsiale-n-kapsuly-30/
```

т.е., тут и catalog и код раздела.

Возможно ли привести его к виду:

```
https://site.com/essentsiale-n-kapsuly-30/
```

Comment: Ответ: Возможно.

Comment: Не подскажете, как?)

Comment: Задайте вопрос так, чтобы ответ содержал решение. @AlexanderSemikashev дал ответ, который заслуживает ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Для инфоблоков, настройка "URL страницы (раздела) информационного блока"

- https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/iblock_edit.php

Для "перезаписи" URL

- https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/urlrewrite.php

Answer (score 1):

В поле `URL страницы детального просмотра` в настройках инфоблока или компонента укажите:

```
#SERVER_NAME#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/
```